# How do I include the path of my CSS file in my web.config?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a problem with my css file. I'm programming with visual studio in asp.net and I want to do a design of my page login. But sometimes, it works and sometimes, it doesn't...

Thanks for your help ;)

This is my code CSS :

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


@import url(http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css);


/* ---------- FONTAWESOME ---------- */

/*[class*="fontawesome-"]:before
{
    font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI" , Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
}*/

/* ---------- GENERAL ---------- */

body
{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI" , Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.input
{
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* ---------- LOGIN ---------- */

#login
{
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 400px;
}

#login h2
{
    background-color: #f95252;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 20px 26px;
}

#login h2 span[class*="fontawesome-"]
{
    margin-right: 14px;
}

#login fieldset
{
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    padding: 20px 26px;
}

#login fieldset p
{
    color: #777;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

#login fieldset p:last-child
{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#login fieldset input
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#UserEmail
{
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #777;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    width: 328px;
}

#login fieldset input[type="email"], #login fieldset input[type="password"]
{
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #777;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    width: 328px;
}

#login fieldset input[type="submit"]
{
    background-color: #33cc77;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4px 0;
    width: 100px;
}

#login fieldset input[type="submit"]:hover
{
    background-color: #28ad63;
}
```

and this is my aspx page :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Logon.aspx.cs" Inherits="projetDGCS1.Logon" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//FR" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Connexion | DGCS</title>
    <link href="css/styleLogin.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="login">
        <h2>
            Connexion</h2>
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label for="email">
                    Nom</label></p>
            <p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="UserEmail" runat="server" CssClass="input" /></p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">
                    Mot de passe</label></p>
            <p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="UserPass" TextMode="Password" runat="server" CssClass="input" /></p>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="Submit1" OnClick="Logon_Click" Text="Se connecter" runat="server" /></p>
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="Msg" ForeColor="red" runat="server" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "But sometimes, it works and sometimes, it doesn't" What does this mean? When doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well for me. The only mistakes I can see are the 'for' attributes on your labels which should match the id attributes of your form elements.
So Nom label should be: `<label for="UserEmail">`
Is this login tied to forms authentication? you might need to add a location path in your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="css/styleLogin.css">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```